# How to identify first and last node and their group from a List - Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and trying to build a graph with my data. I have a nested list and I want to separate 2 set of groups based on the relation so that the output graph will be specific to one group. I am able to get one complete graph but I want to simplify with 2 graph using python as the requirement has thousands of object.

`RelationList=[["A","B"],["B","C"],["B","D"],["D","E"],["X","Y"],["Y","Z"],["Z","U"]]`

**Output :**

```
Graph 1 : 

A->B
B->C
B->D
D->E

Graph 2 :

X->Y
Y->Z
Z->U
```

Please guide me to code.

Comment: How does the question title relate to your problem? You claim to already be able to get one graph, so you seem to have access to first and last element of each pair. What is your condition to separate the graphs? Are you looking for unconnected graphs? Did you try some of the graph libraries available for Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array indexing to get certain elements.  Array indexing work as follows: `array[start:end:step]`

To get the first node, you use `array[0]`, the last node is `array[-1]`, and to get consecutive groups you can use a range such as `array[0:3]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:
First of all create a list with all possible nodes for graph1

```
graph1_nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Once you have that list you have to iterate and compare it with your current RelationList and create a sublist wich would be one of the graphs that you're asking for. For do that create a empty list where will be filled with data of graph1

```
Graph1 = []
Graph2 = []
for node in RelationList:
    # node is the first element of the list
    if node[0] in graph1_nodes:
        # node[0] take the first position of the element
        Graph1.append(node)
    else:
        Graph2.append(node)
```

And finally the output will be this:

```
Graph1 = [["A","B"],["B","C"],["B","D"],["D","E"]]
Graph2 = [["X","Y"],["Y","Z"],["Z","U"]]
```

Hope I've helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Union Find, or Disjoint Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure and algorithm for this. This will work for any number of nodes and subgraphs and it does not matter whether subgraphs are stored in closed regions of the list. This is so useful I always have a simple implementation at hand:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leaders = defaultdict(lambda: None)
    def find(self, x):
        l = self.leaders[x]
        if l is not None:
            l = self.find(l)
            self.leaders[x] = l
            return l
        return x
    def union(self, x, y):
        lx, ly = self.find(x), self.find(y)
        if lx != ly:
            self.leaders[lx] = ly
    def get_groups(self):
        groups = defaultdict(set)
        for x in self.leaders:
            groups[self.find(x)].add(x)
        return list(groups.values())
```

Application to your `RelationList`:

```
RelationList=[["A","B"],["B","C"],["B","D"],["D","E"],["X","Y"],["Y","Z"],["Z","U"]]
uf = UnionFind()
for a, b in RelationList:
    uf.union(a, b)
print(uf.get_groups()) # [{'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'E'}, {'U', 'Z', 'Y', 'X'}]
```